# Is it possible to give enums properties?

Tags: c#, enums, properties

I know you can give them methods by creating an extension method on another class, but are properties possible as well? The best you can do as far as I know is using an extension method that takes zero parameters.

In case you're wondering why I ask this, I have this enum with some custom attributes:

```
enum Operator : byte
{
    [Category(OperatorCategory.Multiplicative), Symbol("")      ] None,
    [Category(OperatorCategory.Additive),       Symbol("+")     ] Add,
    [Category(OperatorCategory.Additive),       Symbol("\u2212")] Subtract,
    [Category(OperatorCategory.Multiplicative), Symbol("\u22C5")] Multiply,
    [Category(OperatorCategory.Multiplicative), Symbol("\u00F7")] Divide,
    [Category(OperatorCategory.Exponential),    Symbol("^")     ] Exponent,
    [Category(OperatorCategory.Exponential),    Symbol("\u221A")] Root,
    [Category(OperatorCategory.Exponential),    Symbol("log")   ] Logarithm
}
```

I want to do a really simple thing: add a `.Category` property that returns the category of the operator (so I don't have to type the same thing all over again).

Comment: Where do you want to add `Category` property, in which place? Why extension method doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: Can you put properties directly into the Enum itself?  No.  But you could use an extension method.  Something like `static OperatorCategory Category(this Operator me) ...` which just checks the attributes or a populated static dictionary.  I don't see what's wrong with doing it this way.

Comment: Of course extension methods work just fine, but normally in this case I'd use a property instead of a method, and I was wondering if that was possible.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article, it might give you some insight into what you want:

[Using Enumeration Classes instead of Enum Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types)

I have not tried this, I just thought it looked relevant. My suggestion was going to be create a class that holds a list of your properties, then the integer based index of the enum, instead of a byte that you used, could be used to retrieve the property value you need based on the enum value.